# Letters and symbols not showing using Arabic script

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia, arabic, letters

I am trying to write a letter in Arabic using the `KacstPen` font. However, the resulting document does not show numerals nor symbols.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Below is the code and the resulting document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,hijricorrection=1,locale=morocco]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setmainfont{KacstPen}


\address{سعيد  \\ دوار مديونة \\ رقم الهاتف: 0655850000}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{إلى السيد: المندوب الجهوي لمؤسسة وسيط المملكة\\ شارع مصطفي لحلو, حي الأدارسة\\ فاس 30040 المغرب}

\opening{\textbf{الموضوع: ملاحظات وتوضيحات حول التظلم عدد 19-24064} \\ \\ \\سلام تام بوجود مولانا الإمام:}


\closing{إمضاء:\\
%\fromsig{\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{signature4.png}} \\
\fromname{سعيد }
}


\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: The font contains only the Arabic-Indic digits, not the glyphs you want.

Comment: @Thérèse Is there a way I can define another font only for digits and symbols?

Comment: How to do that depends on how you’re compiling: xetex? luatex?

Comment: @Thérèse I am compiling using Xelatex.

Comment: I don’t often use xetex, but I think the package `ucharclasses` will do what you want. Search for `ucharclasses` on this site to see examples of its usage.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: If you can use a font that contains the glyphs you need, that might be a better option.

Comment: @Davislor That's what I did eventually. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, the font is called `kacstPen` (not `KacstPen`) and has the  digits.

[image: kacstPen]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,hijricorrection=1,locale=morocco]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setmainfont{kacstPen}


\address{سعيد  \\ دوار مديونة \\ رقم الهاتف: 0655850000}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{إلى السيد: المندوب الجهوي لمؤسسة وسيط المملكة\\ شارع مصطفي لحلو, حي الأدارسة\\ فاس 30040 المغرب}

\opening{\textbf{الموضوع: ملاحظات وتوضيحات حول التظلم عدد 19-24064} \\ \\ \\سلام تام بوجود مولانا الإمام:}


\closing{إمضاء:\\
%\fromsig{\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{signature4.png}} \\
\fromname{سعيد }
}


\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to various font sites, for `kacstPen`, KACST produce the Arabic part, and URW the Latin part. Perhaps `KacstPen` font is just the Arabic one??

Comment: I had to change the font eventually, but I will try using your example. Thanks.